# Animate() divs from a reference point?

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui

I have 9 divs, in rows of 3. When I click one of them I want the others fadeOut (that's ok, any problem) and then the one I clicked resize anything it will need from left, right, top and bottom, until it cover all the 9 divs space. And I got that for the first div in the first row, because it's in the top-left corner, but with the other ones, they go to the top-left corner and then resize, and I want resize them in the place they were when I clicked. And then center the inside of the div of course.

I am trying it with jquery-ui, and I am pretty new with that, so I don't know if it could be very complicated or not. I googled "jquery animate() from reference point", but I didn't get anything..

thanks all!

```
    <div id="row1" class="row-fluid">
    <p id="p1" class="hero-unit span4 ">P número 1</p>
    <p id="p2" class="hero-unit span4 ">P número 2</p>
    <p id="p3" class="hero-unit span4 ">P número 3</p>
    </div>

    <div id="row2" class="row-fluid">
    <p id="p4" class="hero-unit span4 ">P número 4</p>
    <p id="p5" class="hero-unit span4 ">P número 5</p>
    <p id="p6" class="hero-unit span4 ">P número 6</p>
    </div>

    <div id="row3" class="row-fluid">
    <p id="p7" class="hero-unit span4 ">P número 7</p>
    <p id="p8" class="hero-unit span4 ">P número 8</p>
    <p id="p9" class="hero-unit span4 ">P número 9</p>
    </div>


    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("p").click(function() {
            current = $(this);
            $("p").not(this).fadeOut(1000, function(){
                current.animate({
                    margin: "0px",
                    height: "420px",
                    width: "940px",
                }, 1000, function(){
                    current.removeClass("span4");
                }); 
            });
        });
    });
```

Thats' all I have, very simple.

Comment: http://masonry.desandro.com/demos/adding-items.html click on prepend new items hope you are looking for this and post some code what have you done?

Comment: Thanks you Rajat Modi, but is not that I am looking for. I want that if I click "p5", other ones disapear, and p5 expand to the 4 corners until it has all the width and height that I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason its jumping to the top left before it resizes is because all the other `<p>`'s are getting their `display` set to `none`. The solution is to set the current `<p>` to absolute position before it resizes.

try this!

Wrap the HTML in a Div that has relative positioning:

```
<div id='container' style="position: relative;">
    <div id="row1" class="row-fluid">
    <p id="p1" class="hero-unit span4 ">P número 1</p>
    <p id="p2" class="hero-unit span4 ">P número 2</p>
    <p id="p3" class="hero-unit span4 ">P número 3</p>
    </div>

    <div id="row2" class="row-fluid">
    <p id="p4" class="hero-unit span4 ">P número 4</p>
    <p id="p5" class="hero-unit span4 ">P número 5</p>
    <p id="p6" class="hero-unit span4 ">P número 6</p>
    </div>

    <div id="row3" class="row-fluid">
    <p id="p7" class="hero-unit span4 ">P número 7</p>
    <p id="p8" class="hero-unit span4 ">P número 8</p>
    <p id="p9" class="hero-unit span4 ">P número 9</p>
    </div>
</div>​​​​​


$(document).ready(function(){
$("p").click(function(){
    current = $(this);  
    var position = current.position();
    $("p").not(this).fadeOut(1000, function(){
        // set the current position to absolute with the top and left dimensions the same;
        current.css({
            'postition' : 'absolute',
            'left' : position.left,
            'top' : position.top,
        });
        current.animate({
            margin: "0px",
            height: "420px",
            width: "940px"
            top: "0px",
            left: "0px"
        }, 1000, function(){
            current.removeClass("span4");
        }); 
    });

});
});​
```

Note that none of this requires jQuery.UI. it will work on plain jQuery :)

And a here is a jsfiddle to show it in action: http://jsfiddle.net/Fgb9b/1/

Enjoy!

Comment: yes! thanks you! that's exactly what I wanted! Only one problem.. I copied all exactly, and it didn't work... -.- I used the last version of jquery, not jquery.ui, I used normalize.css (I didn't knew it), but it doesnt work.

Comment: Did you see the jsFiddle I linked to? Its working, could you alter your code to make it work like the fiddle? I cant help you any further without seeing more of your code.

Comment: Yes, I saw it, and I copied exactly as is. But mine looks like yours jsFiddle without normalize.css. But I have normalize.css... here is my code: http://pastebin.com/tT2zxE4p
Thanks.

Comment: I see your code is slightly different, in the animation you set it to 300px while on the js fiddle it's set to 150px. Is it not working at all on your website or just working a bit wrong? If its a little bit wrong you need to change the width/height accordingly.

Comment: Sorry for the difference, I was trying some things and forgot to change it again. And the only difference with your jsfiddle is the distance between the rows, you don't have any, and I have 10px more or less, and I don't know why because I only use the normalize.css and the <style> you posted. I tried it in crhrome, chromium and firefox, and yours works fine without padding/margin, but not mine. I think is the normalize.css that is not working, because if I quit of your jsfiddle the normalize.css, it looks exactly like mine. Thanks.